# Why can't .NET parse a date string with a timezone?

Tags: .net, datetime, parsing

.NET throws an exception trying to parse a datetime string in this format:

**Fri, 10 Oct 2008 00:05:51 CST**

Convert.ToDateTime("Fri, 10 Oct 2008 00:05:51 CST") results in an exception:

> The string was not recognized as a
>   valid DateTime. There is a unknown
>   word starting at index 26

Character 26 obviously being the start of "CST"

In a quick test, PHP and javascript can both parse this string into a date with no problem.  Is .NET just full of fail or is there a reasonable explanation?

Comment: Javascript runs on the client, so it can use the locale settings of that computer...PHP is just cruddy and probably assumes. .NET forces you to write culture independent code, so its a little trickier.

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey1cdcx8.aspx

You need to use the overloaded DateTime.Parse to accurately parse timezones.

Answer (score 0):

If a specific date and time format will be parsed across different locales, use one of the overloads of the ParseExact method and provide a format specifier.