# Converting Java Date string into C# DateTime

Tags: c#, java, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse DateTime with timezone of form PST/CEST/UTC/etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241789/parse-datetime-with-timezone-of-form-pst-cest-utc-etc)

OK, I have following code in Java that converts my Date object into String:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz");
String str = dateFormat.format(new Date());
// outputs: 2012-12-17 15:44:57 CST
```

I am sending that String over the wire to WebService written in C#. So, how would I parse back that String into valid DateTime considering that following doesn't work because **zzz** in C# is different:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(parts[2], "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat);
```

And before anyone suggests it - I know I can go with UTC time, but I need to do it this way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicates [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241789/parse-datetime-with-timezone-of-form-pst-cest-utc-etc), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754563/parse-string-datetime-containing-timezone-info), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193095/why-cant-net-parse-a-date-string-with-a-timezone)

Comment: Why do you _need to do it this way_? When calling the web service why not convert the date to whatever format you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CST` is not a valid .NET timezone identifier.

In .NET, these are all numeric offsets - `+0700`, `-0500` etc...

You will need to output a numeric timezone offset if you want it to be parsed by .NET.

I suggest using `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z` in Java, as can be seen [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The alternative is to convert `CST` to `-0600` using `string.Replace`, but this is both not scalable and can fall over with the ambiguities of named timezones (`CST` can mean different timezones depending on where you are).

Comment: You obviously haven't read this part: "So, how would I parse back that String into valid DateTime ___considering that following doesn't work because zzz in C# is different___"

Comment: @kape123 - You either change the Java to use `Z` instead of `zzz` or, in C# convert the named timezones to their numeric equivalents (though the named timezones are ambiguous)

Comment: Didn't know about Z - thanks! So Z on Java side, zzz on C# side and it works perfectly.